# XPath to select parent element if child element is missing

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have some XML like this: `some.xml`:

```
<one>
  <two>
    <three> 
    <four>some text</four>
    </three>
  </two>
  <two>
    <three>
        <four>some other text</four>
    </three>
  </two>
  <two>
  </two>
</one>
```

I can delete any of the `two` elements by searching for a text:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//one/two[contains(.,'some text')]" some.xml
```

This removes the first `two` node. But I want to delete all `two` elements that do not contain any `three` element, like this:

```
<one>
  <two>
    <three> 
    <four>some text</four>
    </three>
  </two>
  <two>
    <three>
        <four>some other text</four>
    </three>
  </two>
</one>
```

Comment: **Thank you** for not wanting to use `sed` or something for this.

Comment: regex came to mind - but brainfuck exists already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on whether by "*contains* any `three` element" you mean (1) or (2)

1. As an *immediate child*:

   ```
   //one/two[not(three)]
   ```

   will select all `two` elements that do not have a `three` child.
2. As any *descendent*

   ```
   //one/two[not(.//three)]
   ```

   will select all `two` elements that do not have a `three` descendent.

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution looks painfully simple :-)
I wonder why i wasn't able to extract that from the documentation  - but all these XSLT comparisons baffle me ...

Answer (score 3):

> i want to delete all "two" Elements that do not contain any "three" Element

If I understand correctly, that would be `xmlstarlet ed -d '//two[not(three)]'`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one>
  <two>
    <three>
      <four>some text</four>
    </three>
  </two>
  <two>
    <three>
      <four>some other text</four>
    </three>
  </two>
</one>
```